# Type 'AVCaptureDevice' has no member 'defaultDevice'

Tags: swift, avcapturedevice

Working on a QR code reader. I am new to programming so this might be an easy fix. The error is "Type 'AVCaptureDevice' has no member 'defaultDevice'" Thanks for the help in advance!

```
 //Creating session
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    //Define capture device
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    do
    {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        session.addInput(input)
    }
```

Comment: check this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1386589-default

Answer (score 27):

You are using the old Swift 2 API. The line:

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
```

should be:

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is swift 3.0

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
```

In swift 4.1

```
AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
{
   let input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
   session.addInput(input)
}
```

I hope this will help you